# Change local password as root after configuring for MS-AD Kerberos+LDAP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ldap, kerberos, passwd

I have followed this excellent post to configure Kerberos + LDAP:
http://koo.fi/blog/2013/01/06/ubuntu-12-04-active-directory-authentication/

However, there are some **local users** used for services.
When I try to change the password for one of those, as root, it asks for `Current Kerberos password` then exits:

```
passwd service1
Current Kerberos password:  (I hit enter)
Current Kerberos password:  (I hit enter)
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

If I switch to the local user and do `passwd`, it asks once for Kerberos then falls back to local:
`$ passwd`
`Current Kerberos password:`
`Changing password for service1.`
`(current) UNIX password:`

My configuration is similar to the site I posted above, and everything works fine, I just can't change the local users' passwords as root.

Thanks in advance for any help.

`3.8.0-29-generic #42~precise1-Ubuntu`

## Update 1 2013-01-31:

```
# cat /etc/pam.d/common-auth
auth    [success=3 default=ignore]      pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure try_first_pass
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
auth    optional                        pam_cap.so


# cat /etc/pam.d/common-password
password        [success=3 default=ignore]      pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000
password        [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass sha512
password        [success=1 user_unknown=ignore default=die]     pam_ldap.so use_authtok try_first_pass
password        requisite                       pam_deny.so
password        required                        pam_permit.so
password        optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
```

Comment: What is the full path to your passwd command?

Comment: /usr/bin/passwd

Comment: The next thing is to look at the pam config for passwd. What does /etc/pam.d/passwd look like?

Comment: @include common-password

Comment: Found something on the link below. Could something on common-auth be forcing Kerberos instead of allowing local? I'll post the contents. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846429/change-local-linux-password-when-joined-to-active-directory)

Comment: It looks like pam_krb5 is not honoring the minumum_uid for password changes. Or else your local accounts have uid > 1000.

Comment: Fred, thank you so much for the help. The users were created without -u setting a lower UID.    Cheers!

Answer (score 20):

In your /etc/pam.d/common-password , change the minimum_uid in your first line to something bigger than 1000, example:

```
password        [success=3 default=ignore]      pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=10000
```

That worked for me. This is what you should see in /var/log/auth.log after changing the password for that user as root:

```
Dec 26 12:34:36 3.8.0-29-generic passwd[22667]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): password changed for service1
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The line with pam_krb5.so should have minimum_uid of the starting uid of your kerberos users.

Comment: You can change all pam files at once: `sudo sed -i 's/minimum_uid=1000\b/minimum_uid=10000/g' /etc/pam.d/common-*`.

Answer (score 3):

@Ameer's answer about editing **`common-password`** is correct. But: when you edit the uid limits of PAM in general, don't forget to edit all the affected PAM files! If you search for `krb5` in `/etc/pam.d`, you should find all the relevant files:

```
root@server:/etc/pam.d# grep -R krb5 .
./common-auth:auth  [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=10000
./common-session-noninteractive:session optional            pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=10000
./common-session:session    optional            pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=10000
./common-account:account    required            pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=10000
./common-password:password  [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=10000
```

If, for example, you've only edited **`common-auth`**, but not **`common-password`**, authentication works with local accounts, but `passwd` still asks for the current kerberos password! (Which is exactly the mistake that led me here.)

Answer (score 1):

An indirect way to do it. Use `mkpasswd` to generate encrypted password:

```
mkpasswd --method=sha-512
```

Then use `usermod` to change the user's password:

```
usermod -p '<encrypted_password_from_mkpasswd>' <username>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your users are using kerberos password you can remove kerberos password management from pam, because the kerberos password can be changed with command `kpasswd`

Answer (score 0):

No need to install anything extra or modify pam settings to change a local password.

`sudo usermod -p "$(echo "password" | openssl passwd -stdin -6)" user`

The `-6` means SHA512 encryption, for some older linux systems, you could need to replace it with a `-1` or a `-5`.

Reference: https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/openssl_passwd.1.asp